# How do I make a square whose border is made of numbers? [Inkscape]

Tags: inkscape, shapes, section-marker

I'd like to create squares, but instead of solid or dashed borders, I want them composed of numbers (like -1-). However, if I make a marker with numbers, and apply it to the squares, it doesn't work! Nothing happens. Help?

[image]

Comment: You could construct a box by typing lines of numbers, and then reposition them to form a rectangle or square.  Would this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Use the 'Pattern along Path' LPE (or the corresponding extension - description is for LPE)

- Make your design (a dash and a number, or maybe a second dash, too)
- convert those to a path (you might need 'stroke to path' for the dash), and combine them to a single path
- copy that to clipboard
- select the rectangle
- apply the LPE to it: Path > Path effects > + > Pattern along Path
- Paste the number to the LPE (there's an icon for it at the top)
- Adjust parameters until it looks about right

Cons: it's not easy to get this working on the corners.
Pros: can be adjusted any time

[image: LPE]

Option 2:

- add nodes. Markers need a node to show up. So convert your rectangle to a path, then use the 'add nodes' extension to add nodes all around, or add them by selecting all nodes, and then using the 'add new node in the middle of segment' functionality a couple of times.

Pros: less complicated to do with what you already have
Cons: you only get regular intervals with the extension (I didn't use it in my example, see below)

[image: with markers]